# Is running a query directly from an Axon aggregate's command handler OK with CQRS?

Tags: cqrs, axon

This is more of a theoretical question related to CQRS and Axon. Below is a self-explanatory setup, the code is **a pseudo-code**, it is not meant to compile.

Assuming that in order to process a command from an aggregate "Foo" we need first to query a state of another aggregate "Bar" for validation (from another bounded context, so it's not a question of a simple lookup of the "Foo"'s member aggregates).

We have two choices here as illustrated in the pseudo-code. Choice (1), we just run the query from the command handler in the "Foo" aggregate using the query gateway.

Choice (2), we apply an event asking a dedicated service to handle the querying instead of "Foo". The service then will dispatch a command back to "Foo" after it has queried the system for the state of "Bar".

Does the first choice (**querying directly** from the command handler) seems to go against the whole idea of Command-Query separation -- after all, this way we *are* executing a query during a command processing, right?

The second choice seems more in the spirit of CQRS: the command just results in an event (which later will result in an another command, etc.). But obviously, this comes at a cost: there are more steps involved, 2a, 2b, 2c, 2d...

I would like to hear what the community thinks about this. For me, it seems bizarre if we are strict about not mixing commands with query processing but are allowing executing queries with command processing. Or am I missing something?

```java
@Aggregate
class AggregateFoo {

    private QueryGateway queryGateway;

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(UpdateFooCommand command){

        /*
            Assume that in order to validate this command we first need
            to query the state of another aggregate, "Bar".
        */

        // 1. We can just issue the query directly from the command handler.

        queryGateway
            .query(new AskForStateOfBarQuery(command.getBarId()))
            .then(queryResponse -> {
                // Proceed with original command execution depending
                // the result of the query response.    
            });

        // 2a. Or we can issue an intermediate EVENT offloading the query handling
        //     to a dedicated service ("FooBarService", see below).

        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new FooUpdateValidationRequestedEvent(command.getBarId()));

    }

    // 2d. "Foo" aggregate will react to the validation command from the
    //     dedicated service effectively executing the original command.

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(ProceedWithFooUpdateCommand command){

        // Do other validations, issue events here. At this
        // point we know that UpdateFooCommand was validated.
    } 

}

@Service
class FooBarService {

    private QueryGateway queryGateway;
    private CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @EventHandler
    public void on(FooUpdateValidationRequestedEvent event){
        
        // 2b. The dedicated service will run the corresponding query,
        //     asking for the state of "Bar".
        
        queryGateway
            .query(new AskForStateOfBarQuery(command.getBarId()))
            .then(queryResponse -> {

                // 2c. And will issue a COMMAND to the "Foo" aggregate
                //     indicating that it shoud proceed with the original 
                //     command's (UpdateFooCommand) execution.

                commandGateway.send(new ProceedWithFooUpdateCommand(command.getFooId()));

            });

    }

}
```

---

UPDATE:

This is an update after the discussion of the informative answer given by 91stefan (see below).

```java
class AggregateFoo {
    int f = 9;

    // reference to the related Bar aggregate
    UUID bar;

    on(UpdateFooCommand){
        // Assume we must execute ONLY IF f < 10 AND bar.b > 10.
        // So we apply event to Saga (with f = 9), 
        // Saga will ask Bar: (b = 15), so the condition holds
        // and Saga issues ConfirmValidBarStateCommand
    }

    // Meanwhile, when Saga is busy validating, we process another
    // command CHANGING the state of Foo
    on(AnotherCommand) { f++; }

    // or "ConfirmValidBarStateCommand" as in 91stefan's example
    on(ProceedWithFooUpdateCommand){
        // So when we get back here (from Saga), there is no guarantee
        // that the actual state of Foo (f < 10) still holds,
        // and that we can proceed with the execution of the
        // original UpdateFooCommand
    }

}

class AggregateBar {
    int b = 15;
}
```

So looks like the question still holds: how to validate and execute a command consistently in Foo if its validation depends on the state of Bar from another bounded context? Looks like we may have several choices here:

- direct query from Foo's command handler for a projected state of Bar
- event to a (stateless) service which queries Bar for a projected state
- (91stefan's suggestion) event to a Saga which sends validation command to Bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might face issues, querying from the command handler is not considered a good practice as your projection might not be up-to-date due to eventual consistency. Also, command handlers from same aggregate are executed sequentially/synchronously. You just want to do quick stuff, calling external services will block and prevent other commands from aggregate from executing until the current command handler finishes execution.

What you need in this case is Saga.
https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/3.3/part-ii-domain-logic/sagas

Simplify flow would be:

- commandHandler(UpdateFooCommand) -> applyEvent(AskedForStateOfBarEvent)
- AskedForStateOfBarEvent starts Saga
- Inside saga, send command to Bar aggregate -> ConfirmYourStateBar(barAggregateId)
- commandHandler(ConfirmYourStateBar) -> validate state -> applyEvent(StateIsValidatedEvent)
- Saga reacts to StateIsValidatedEvent, sends command to AggregateFoo -> (ConfirmValidBarStateCommand(aggreageFooId) & saga is closed (end event is StateIsValidatedEvent)
- In commandHandler(ConfirmValidBarStateCommand) you proceed your execution, as your state BAR state is valid

Comment: Thank you for the input. You are right about being careful with holding the thread during the command validation while waiting for the query result to arrive. That's why in my second scenario (steps 2a-2d) there is offloading of the task of validation to the dedicated service through an event. Your suggestion of a Saga instead of a service goes in the same direction, except there will have to be one instance of the Saga for each command validation (for each instance of AggregateFoo asking for validation) and moreover Sagas have to be persisted. This may or may not be an acceptable overhead.

Comment: The question remains though: do we _really_ have to go all the way of "event-Saga/service-query-command" each time we need to ask for a state of the system when validating commands in the aggregate? This just seems like a lot of work for a fairly common thing, i.e. validation of a command across bounded contexts.

Comment: If you want consistency, and state in aggregate that you depend on can change often, unfortunately, yes. Usually, you should have no more than a few sagas, if you have to do validation for many command handlers, then you should rethink if the design of your aggregates and contexts can be more efficient. Also, you can avoid stateful saga (storing state in db), and create a stateless saga using external event handlers and configure deadline manager that will dispatch event if your states "saga" hasn't complete in the expected timeframe. This is the approach that I often use.

Comment: Interesting, after reading your answer again I've noticed that there is a slight difference in our approaches. Yours does not actually involve querying at all. The validation Saga uses _command_ to ask if AggregateBar is in a valid state (presumably by sending the state of the AggregateFoo at the time of the original command in the command context). This, indeed has an advantage of validating the original UpdateFooCommand in the context of the actual state of AggregateBar. Whereas, in my case (2), the query will be processed by some query handler recording _the projection_ of the Bar's state.

Comment: However, in the case in question, we are talking about validating some precondition involving two different bounded contexts. So, I think, it is justified to take the risk of validating UpdateFooCommand _based on the projection of Bar's state_ instead of actual state of AggregateBar. Especially since it is precisely the role of the projection (also acting as a query handler) to store _related contexts_ (between Foo and Bar) against which the actual validation may take place.

Comment: But there is much more interesting point here. By the time either a service or a Saga has issued a command `ConfirmValidBarStateCommand` (as in your example)
the state of AggregateFoo may have _already changed_ in the way that the validation performed earlier is no longer relevant.

Comment: Please see the update portion of the question as well.

Comment: I would still argue that using a query is a good idea. It is after all just a "projection". It can be destroyed at any time, changed, and created again via events replay. If creating full saga is big overhead for you, you may just send validation command to bounded context, do validation in the command handler and return value from command handler if validation is successful.  Ofcourse send command using sendAndWait

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you are suggesting, sending a validation command directly from Foo's command handler? Something like this:
`@CommandHandler
on(UpdateFooCommand){commandGateway.sendAndWait(barUuid, IsYourStateValidCommand).then(answer -> /* proceed if true */)}`
This indeed would be much simpler, and we should not wait for Bar to answer for too long, so it's ok to wait in the same thread.

Comment: It's just looks strange to issue a command from a command handler. Is it OK with CQRS? Commands should just result in one or several events (not other commands). And "IsYourStateValidCommand" is not really a command (its not meant to change the state). But I like this better than query or events to Saga approach. Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

What I know is like below:

For the first option : Query side may not be up2date, so this may cause wrong business decision, as it is already mentioned.

For the second and third options : A query is a query, event is a fact. Triggering events for query result seems like to misuse/hacky. I cant imagine how many events will be stored in the aggregate after a while. Using a saga also for this purpose seems like to be misuse. Sagas should be processing chain of events(AskedForStateOfBarEvent does not seems like to be state change(event) for an aggregate)

There are some hints for Command Handlers [here](https://developer.axoniq.io/w/how-do-i-enhance-events-with-data-that-is-not-part-of-the-aggregate-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).